# catkin build can't find shared library from a dependent package

Tags: ros, dependencies, library, cmake, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've Just started using `catkin_tools`, and `catkin build`.  It seems to require more precicely specified CMakeLists.txt files, and this is causing my grief at the moment.

I have package_A that depends on package_B's shared library.  They are both within the one workspace.
When I `catkin build package_A`, package_B is built first, and it's shared library is placed in `devel/lib`.  However, when package_A is linked, I get an error saying it can't find the library generated by package_B.

In package_A's CMakeLists.txt:

- I have used `find_package (package_B)`,
- I have included package_B in the `catkin_package( CATKIN_DEPENDS )` section,
- I have package_B mentioned in the `target_link_libraries` for the package_A target.

In package_B's CMakeLists.txt:

- I have package_B mentioned in `catkin_package ( LIBRARIES )` section.

*If I add a line `link_directories(${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/lib})` then it works fine.  However, this doesn't look like the proper solution to me.*

Any suggestions on what I'm missing / doing wrong?

Cheers,
Nap

Here are the CMakeLists.txt files from the packages in full:

Package_A:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(whiteboard_test)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS gusimplewhiteboard)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  CATKIN_DEPENDS gusimplewhiteboard
)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c99")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -DWHITEBOARD_POSTER_STRING_CONVERSION=1")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath -Wl,${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")

include_directories(
    include
    ${gusimplewhiteboard_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

###  THIS LINE IS REQUIRED TO FIND THE LIBRARY????? ###
link_directories(${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/lib)

add_executable(whiteboard_test
    src/whiteboard_test.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(whiteboard_test
    gusimplewhiteboard
    ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
    ${LIBDISPATCH_LIBRARIES}
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
    dispatch
)
add_dependencies(whiteboard_test
    gusimplewhiteboard
)
```

**SOLVED BY:**

Removing:

```
###  THIS LINE IS REQUIRED TO FIND THE LIBRARY????? ###
link_directories(${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/lib)
```

and changing `target_link_libraries` statement to:

```
target_link_libraries(whiteboard_test
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
    ${LIBDISPATCH_LIBRARIES}
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
    dispatch
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210040/catkin-build-can%27t-find-shared-library-from-a-dependent-package/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2015-05-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-28**:
It would probably help (or at least, help *me*) if you include the actual snippets from your `CMakeLists.txt` that you're using, instead of an abstracted version. Not the entire text, just the bits that are important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not need:

> - I have package_B mentioned in the target_link_libraries for the
>   package_A target.

and

> add a line
> link_directories(${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/lib})

If you add a lib created in a package in the same package's CMakeLists.txt `catkin_package ( LIBRARIES )` section as you did here

> - I have package_B mentioned in catkin_package ( LIBRARIES ) section.

and find_package the package in a depending package as you did here

> - I have used find_package (package_B),

, the lib will automatically linked against targets in all depending packages.

Hint:

For this to work you need, as for all targets using ros functions, to link against `catkin_LIBRARIES`

```
target_link_libraries( your_target ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-05-28**:
thanks Wolf, I did as you suggested and it worked.
I had to add `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` **AND** remove the reference to the shared library (*gusimplewhiteboard* in my case) from the `target_link_libraries` statement.